# kernel and range of a linear operator in a reflexive space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and $T:X\to X$ is a linear operator. Is it true that
$$
X = \mathrm{ker}(I-T) \oplus \overline{\mathrm{range}(I-T^\ast)},
$$
where $\oplus$ is the direct sum?

I know this is true when $X$ is a Hilbert space (due to the fact that $Tx=x$ implies $T^\ast x =x$), and I would suspect something like that is true when $T$ is a compact operator. How about the general case?

Comment: This isn't even true in finite dimensional spaces unless you take some further assumptions (such as $T = T^*$)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What if range(I-T) is changed to range(I-T*)?

Comment: Then that's at least correct in the finite dimensional case

Comment: What does it mean to add a subspace of $X$ and  a subspace of $X^{*}$?

Answer (score 0):

This fails even in finite dimension. Let $X=\mathbb C^2$, and 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $(I-T)^2=0$, so $$\overline{\operatorname{ran}(I-T)}\subset\ker(I-T).$$

When $X$ is a Hilbert space, it is true that 
$$\tag1
X=\ker T\oplus \overline{\operatorname{ran} T^*}
$$ 
for any bounded linear operator $T$, since $\overline{\operatorname{ran} T^*}=(\ker T)^\perp$.

For a general Banach space, the equality $(1)$ makes no sense, as $\ker T\subset X$ and $\operatorname{ran} T^*\subset X^*$.

More dramatically, it is known that any Banach space that is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space has a non-complemented subspace $M$. And if $X$ is separable, it is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114434/22857) that there exists a bounded linear $T:X\to X$ with $\ker T=M$. This impedes $(1)$ in general, and there is nothing you can put on the second summand that will make it work.

Comment: For a general Banach space, will it make sense in the sense of isomorphism?

Comment: No. I have edited the answer.